# Using jQuery selector to edit posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my onclick function to respond when the user clicks the edit post link. Currently only the 1st edit post link is working.  Not sure what's wrong as the jQuery should retrieve all elements with post class then retrieve all those with the interaction class and finally the third anchor element that is its descendant, and respond with a console message when the user clicks the link.

```js
$('.post').find('.interaction').find('a').eq(2).on('click', function() {
  console.log('It works!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="row posts">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <header><h3>What other people say...</h3></header>
              <article class="post">
          <p>Post for edit</p>
            <div class="info">
              Posted by danny on 2017-01-16 17:13:17
            </div>
            <div class="interaction">
              <a href="#">Like</a> |
              <a href="#">Dislike</a> |
                              <a href="#">Edit</a> |
                <a href="http://urlproject.dev/delete-post/8">Delete</a>
              
            </div>
        </article>
              <article class="post">
          <p>Another post!</p>
            <div class="info">
              Posted by danny on 2017-01-16 17:12:57
            </div>
            <div class="interaction">
              <a href="#">Like</a> |
              <a href="#">Dislike</a> |
                              <a href="#">Edit</a> |
                <a href="http://urlproject.dev/delete-post/7">Delete</a>
              
            </div>
        </article>
              <article class="post">
          <p>I&#039;m None</p>
            <div class="info">
              Posted by none on 2017-01-12 21:42:44
            </div>
            <div class="interaction">
              <a href="#">Like</a> |
              <a href="#">Dislike</a> |
              
            </div>
        </article>
          </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be much better to give those `a` elements a decent class name?

Comment: Yes, you are correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method selects a single element from the entire selected elements collection based on the index.

To get all the third child `a` use [`:nth-child(3)`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) or [`:nth-of-type(3)`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) for more specific.

```
$('.post .interaction a:nth-of-type(3)').on('click', function() {
  console.log('It works!');
});
```

---

**FYI :** It's always better to use a common class for edit button and select them using it.

For example, if you give `edit` class for all edit button :

```
$('.edit').on('click', function() {
  console.log('It works!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code

```
var abc=$('.post').
find('.interaction').find('a').eq(2);

$(document).on('click', abc,function() {
  console.log('It works!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
$('.post').on('click', '.interaction a',  function(e) {
  if ( 'Edit' === $(e.currentTarget).text() ) {
     console.log('It works!');
  }
});
```

would work even if you move the position of the edit link, although adding a class to the link would be better

if you use

```
   <a  class="edit" href="#">Edit</a>
```

you can use

```
$('.post').on('click', '.interaction a.edit',  function(e) {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a css class to the anchor say edit and then do the following

`$('.edit').on('click', function() {
  console.log('It works!');
});`

Answer (score 1):

For future purposes, I would highly recommend adding it's own class because if Edit changes from it's position in the list of links, it will just break the JavaScript.

It's also a good practice to cache the selector into a variable, and also to separate your event's callback function from the binding.

```js
// Cache the links (to improve performance).
var $editLinks = $('.edit-link');


// Separate function from binding.
var handleEditLinkClick = function(e) {
  console.log('It works!');
};


// Bind function to event
$editLinks.on('click', handleEditLinkClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="row posts">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <header><h3>What other people say...</h3></header>
              <article class="post">
          <p>Post for edit</p>
            <div class="info">
              Posted by danny on 2017-01-16 17:13:17
            </div>
            <div class="interaction">
              <a href="#">Like</a> |
              <a href="#">Dislike</a> |
              <a class="edit-link" href="#">Edit</a> |
                <a href="http://urlproject.dev/delete-post/8">Delete</a>
              
            </div>
        </article>
              <article class="post">
          <p>Another post!</p>
            <div class="info">
              Posted by danny on 2017-01-16 17:12:57
            </div>
            <div class="interaction">
              <a href="#">Like</a> |
              <a href="#">Dislike</a> |
              <a class="edit-link" href="#">Edit</a> |
                <a href="http://urlproject.dev/delete-post/7">Delete</a>
              
            </div>
        </article>
              <article class="post">
          <p>I&#039;m None</p>
            <div class="info">
              Posted by none on 2017-01-12 21:42:44
            </div>
            <div class="interaction">
              <a href="#">Like</a> |
              <a href="#">Dislike</a> |
            </div>
        </article>
          </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you query will also work if you set the eq(2) like ('a:eq(2)')

```js
$('.interaction').find('a:eq(2)').click( function() {
  console.log('It works!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="row posts">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <header><h3>What other people say...</h3></header>
              <article class="post">
          <p>Post for edit</p>
            <div class="info">
              Posted by danny on 2017-01-16 17:13:17
            </div>
            <div class="interaction">
              <a href="#">Like</a> |
              <a href="#">Dislike</a> |
                              <a href="#">Edit</a> |
                <a href="http://urlproject.dev/delete-post/8">Delete</a>
              
            </div>
        </article>
              <article class="post">
          <p>Another post!</p>
            <div class="info">
              Posted by danny on 2017-01-16 17:12:57
            </div>
            <div class="interaction">
              <a href="#">Like</a> |
              <a href="#">Dislike</a> |
                              <a href="#">Edit</a> |
                <a href="http://urlproject.dev/delete-post/7">Delete</a>
              
            </div>
        </article>
              <article class="post">
          <p>I&#039;m None</p>
            <div class="info">
              Posted by none on 2017-01-12 21:42:44
            </div>
            <div class="interaction">
              <a href="#">Like</a> |
              <a href="#">Dislike</a> |
              
            </div>
        </article>
          </div>
  </section>
```